# Stop Action in SpriteKit with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

In a tetris-like game, I am trying to use actions to move the Shapes down and then when the next shape is called, it will stop the previous shape from moving, so that they arent both moving. I have tried to use `removeAllActions` and `removeActionForKey` in a lot of other questions asked on this and also in the SKNode Documentation but it doesnt seem to be working. I tested `actionForKey` on my code and it appears it's not picking up any action that is being carried out even though the other shapes are still moving.

I first call my `doMethod` function inside of the `didMoveToView` which generates the shape and then starts to move it as follows. This is called whenever I press a button so I can control when each new shape is create.

```
func doMethod(){
    if(true){
        if(number_of_blocks != 1){
            current_min = current_max + 1
        }
        // calculate points for shape
        var box_d = createBox(self.size.width/2, yinit: 7*self.size.height/8)
        // using box_d, make a SKNode with each calculated value
        makeBox(box_d)
        // move the blocks down
        MoveBlocks()
        number_of_blocks++
    }
}
```

Then my `MoveBlocks` function is as follows

```
func MoveBlocks(){
    if(number_of_blocks > 1){
        let newnum = number_of_blocks - 1
        let KeyName = "MoveBlocks_"+String(newnum)
        let ActName = actionForKey(KeyName) // returns nil
        // removeAllActions()
        // removeActionForKey(KeyName)
    }


    var Sprite = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(current_min))
    var y_min = (Sprite?.position.y)
    // calc y_min to stop when gets to bottom - not currently implemented correctly
    for i in current_min...(current_max-1){
        var CurrentSprite = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(i))
        if(CurrentSprite?.position.y < y_min){
            y_min = (CurrentSprite?.position.y)
        }
    }
    if(y_min > CGFloat(BOX_WIDTH/2)){
        for i in current_min...current_max {
            var CurrentSprite = childNodeWithName("BOX_"+String(i))
            //var current_pos = sprite_self?.position.y
            //sprite_self?.position.y = (sprite_self?.position.y)! - CGFloat(BOX_WIDTH/2)
            let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: -60), duration: 0.001)
            let pauseAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.999)
            let runSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, pauseAction])
            var KeyName = "MoveBlocks_"+String(number_of_blocks)
            CurrentSprite?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(runSequence), withKey: KeyName)
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented out the other `removeAllActions` and `removeActionForKey` just to show what I had originally. Also, the first bit of `MoveBlocks` is just there so that when the first shape is generated, it doesnt try to stop any actions as there arent any. Then it will for the second, third and so on.

I have a feeling that it's something to do with how I'm actually creating the Action in the first place but I'm not too sure.

Comment: removeAllActions only removes from the scene, not your current sprite, You need to call removeactions on the sprites as well. `CurrentSprite?.removeAllActions`

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Oh yeah thanks! I implemented a for loop just like in the end of `MoveBlocks()` and did what you said and it worked. Thanks! Do you have any tutorials like that except done with swift rather than objective-c?

Comment: just browse that site, there are tons there

Comment: Cool thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different thought, could you build these as physics bodies then on contact with the other blocks remove their actions to "freeze" them?  Just a thought.

Comment: I was thinking of that actually! I might give it a go to see how it gets on!

Comment: You can get some really fine control of the bodies:                                                                               `func evalBorderContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
        let conA = Int(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask)
        let conB = Int(contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
        //        case bottemEdge = 16
        //        case topEdge = 32    
        if conB == 16 {
            contact.bodyA.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, +10))
        } else if conA == 16 {
            contact.bodyB.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, +10))'               (Just a snippet)